# Moved ios project to cocoapods, storyboard loses styling in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I installed cocoapods and created an xcworkspace for my iOS app. If i open the original xcodeproj, my Main.Storyboard appears in XCode with all formatting, using the image assets.

[image: Main.Storyboard in xcodeproj]

However when I open the xcworkspace created for cocoapods support, the Main.Storyboard is weirdly formatted.

[image: Main.Storyboard in xcworkspace]

Note: when i run the app everything is styled appropriately. Its only in the design view that it has this issue. How can I fix this?

My podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout'

target 'SpotDecision' do

end

target 'SpotDecisionTests' do

end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your podspec. Although I imagine this is because you didn't include the appropriate resource files.

Comment: Added the podfile. If I didnt include resource files then when I run in the simulator it shouldn't be styled? However the styling is fine in the simulator. Its only in the design view that its missing.

Answer (score 1):

I Think, I am face this problem. But Unfortunately I was resolve same one.

Please follow the step.

- 1) After install OR Update your pod
- 2) Launch your App.
- 3) Check your    Resource Folder. It's may be    empty
- 4) Delete    Resource folder in your    App.
- 5) Same, Delete       Resource folder in    your App directory.
- 6)    Put    fresh Resource       folder with image in    your
  project    directory.
- 7) Open    your App    and    add resource       folder.
- 8)   Delete Derived Data. Clean & Build Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

May it be that you forgotten to switch the right "Scale of an Interface"? In the bottom of the storyboard.